# Django model fields not appearing in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a relatively simple model in my Django project (I should note that the wording is weird in that the app itself is called 'games' and within it the model is Game but I'll change this later):

```
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
    player_turn = models.IntegerField(),
    game_state = models.BooleanField(),
    rolled = models.BooleanField(),
    rolled_double = models.BooleanField(),
    last_roll = models.IntegerField(),
    test_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200),
```

with a settings.py file in the main folder of the project showing

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'games.apps.GamesConfig',
]
```

and games/admin.py looks like this
from django.contrib import admin

```
from .models import Game

admin.site.register(Game)
```

When I try to run 'python3 manage.py makemigrations' it shows that no changes are detected (even if I arbitrarily change the Game model to test the effect) and when I go into the admin site to add a new game there are no fields available to edit like there are for the User and Group models.  The model itself shows up in the admin site but without any fields.  Right now I'm following along the MDN Django tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models) and it seems like I'm following all of the necessary steps so can someone let me know what I might be forgetting to do?

I'd be happy to post any other code that might be helpful if needed.  Images of site admin are below.  Thanks in advance.

[image: Main Site Admin]
[image: Game Info]
[image: Add Game]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove all the commas (',') after each field in the model and try to makemigrations and migrate and then check the admin panel

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player_turn = models.IntegerField()
    game_state = models.BooleanField()
    rolled = models.BooleanField()
    rolled_double = models.BooleanField()
    last_roll = models.IntegerField()
    test_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Comment: haha chill bro, we all learn from our mistakes only, when you come from a different programming language to python, we make this kind of mistakes, anyways glad to help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much! `makemigrations` kept deleting my fields and they weren't showing up in the admin view, and this was the issue! Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score -1):

If you have (, comma) after every field entry just remove it...i spend some time to find it ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).